# Change content after seven days in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I am having a model say record. There are some records say 10 in table. Now I want to display each record for seven days and change it.
For example:
1. AA.
2. BB.
3. CC.
4. DD.
and so on..
For first seven days I want to display AA after seven days completed I want to hide AA amd show BB, then hide BB and show CC and so on.
In short I need to display only one data at a time for seven days and then change it with the next one. Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class YourController < ActionController
  START_DATE = Date.parse("3/12/2013")
  MAX_RECORDS  = 10 # Set this value to the number of records you have

  def entry_index_to_display
    today = Date.today
    interval = (today - START_DATE).to_i
    index = (interval/7.0).floor
    #index = (index>index.floor)? (index.floor + 1) : index
    index % MAX_RECORDS
  end

  def the_method
    offset = entry_index_to_display
    @record = Record.limit(1).offset(offset).first
    # Find the record using this index.
    # Use this record in the view to display

  end
end
```

Comment: The return value of the entry_index_to_display will be the index of the entry that you would want to display for that week. It changes every week. Also, after all the possible entries are done, it will again go back to first entry. 
Let me know if you need any further customization. Hope, this helps.

Comment: I did'nt understand the purpose of start date. I guess, I have to use created_at for all records and display them in ascending order for 7 days and then change it. It is possible that records are created on same day then how I would iterate through it. Do I need to subtract Date.today with created_at ??

Comment: You will need a reference day to calculate if TODAY is day-1 or day-7 or day-10. So, that's what START-DATE is for. You could also use START_DATE as the created_at.to_date of your 1st record.

Comment: I am still confused, how would I iterate for other records? If I set START_DATE to my first record then how I would be able to keep a track of others? And if suppose there are records which are created on same day then?? Also, suppose I am having an array "records" which holds 10 data(as specified in above question). How I am suppose to use "records" in method since its an array.

Comment: START_DATE should be a hard-coded value. Only when you compare with a fixed-start-point, can you call today as day-1, tomorrow as day-2. So, START_DATE should be a static value. When you run the same code a week later, the return_index will be 2.

Comment: Your method is helpful, but there is one problem. It will always returns 1 first time but if suppose records are deleted and the start id  in table is 15 then,it will fail. It failed for me as my first record id was 38.

Comment: Check the updated code. Use the index as the offset for the record, not the ID.

Comment: Documentation for the limit &offset: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you want to build something similar to a system that displays new users different advertisings or tips within the first weeks. I would use a hash to configure this, because it is easy to read and to understand:

```
DISPLAY_RULES = { 7.days => 'AA', 14.days => 'BB', 21.days => 'CC', ... }

def current_advertising
  rule = DISPLAY_RULES.find { |days, item| days.ago < current_user.created_at }

  Advertising.where(name: rule.last) if rule
end
```

Comment: But display rules are hardcoded.. and if suppose there are 1000 records it won't be feasible to declare 1000 records.

Comment: @rank: You are right. I did not think about situations where someone wants to have so many rules. Btw in your question you wrote: *There are some records say 10 in table*. Do you want the list to cycle (to start again if it came to an end)?

Comment: I said "say" 10, I was just using an example. I don't want to start it again. I just wanted to display records according to they've been created.Albeit, I've accepted one answer but I would love to see if there is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a scheduler and run it daily. Add a column in the table called 'active' which will let you know which one is active and then increment to next one.

For this you can use [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever).